# Roll a die. And construct three events that are not independent but each is independent of the intersection of the other two.

Tags: probability, independence

The question is actually from Billingsley's *Probability and Measure* problem 4.6.

The full question: In a space of six equally likely points (a die is rolled) find three events that are not independent even though each is independent of the intersection of the other two.

Comment: What about the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about rolling a six, rolling a five and rolling a four?

Rolling a four and a five is trivially independent to rolling a four since it is impossible. But Rolling a four and rolling six, or rolling a four and rolling five are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Got it, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: any event is independent of the empty set.

Comment: Very useful hint. Thanks!